# Dll loaded by application only in qt debugger but not independently

Tags: c++, qt, dll, plugins

After cleaning and reinstalling windows 7, I've installed qt 5.11. However, my old plugin (dll) which I developed using qt 3 is no longer recognized by the application. But the application recognizes the dll in debugger mode. 
I have tried copying dependent libraries which the debugger loads to the dll location but this has not worked. I have also removed references to qtcore etc but even this has not worked. I do not know what I am missing.The plugin ran fine in the old version  of qt but not in the newer version of qt. 
Thanks for any help that you can give.

Comment: Any errors? warnings? what is output?

Comment: There are no errors or warnings. The dll compiles fine. But the program simply does not recognize the dll. However when I run the dll in debugger the application recognizes the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt does not provides binary backward compatibility between major versions. 
You must update (== compile and build your plugin dll with Qt5)  to have it working.

see this page 
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Version-Compatibility#Binary_Compatibility_Guidelines